# How to find and change Text of a Label control inside a Datalist footer OnSelectionChanged of a dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to find and change Text of a Label control inside a Datalist footer OnSelectionChanged of a dropdown list inside the ItemTemplate of the same datalist?
I have tried the following OnSelectionChanged of a dropdown list:

```
var ddlList = (DropDownList)sender;
DataList DataList1 = (DataList)FindControl("DataList1");    
foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items)
{
    totals += Convert.ToInt32(lblNewTotal.Text);
    if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
    {
        Label GrandTotal = (Label)ddlList.NamingContainer.FindControl("lblGrand");
        GrandTotal.Text = totals.ToString();
    }
}
```

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried item.Controls.FindControl()?

Comment: @hallie Can you explain it briefly?